# Is Lotus notes email client unable to render <br > tag?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, icalendar

I have a weird problem with Lotus Notes 8.5. In my project I am sending meeting invitation to the user. for that, I generate .ics file. Here is how i generate .ics file

```
var body = "Dear Raj, \n\n How are you? line break is not working \n\n how?";
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("../test.ics"))
{
    writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    writer.WriteLine("PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN");
    writer.WriteLine("VERSION:2.0");
    writer.WriteLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
    writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
    writer.WriteLine("ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:participant@company.com");
    writer.WriteLine("ORGANIZER;CN="Organizer":MAILTO:organizer@test.ccc");
    writer.WriteLine("(DTSTART:20141231T010000Z");
    writer.WriteLine("DTEND:20141231T010000Z");
    writer.WriteLine("TRANSP:OPAQUE");
    writer.WriteLine("SEQUENCE:0");
    writer.WriteLine("UID:Company-interview-123");
    writer.WriteLine("DTSTAMP:20141223T232322Z");
    writer.WriteLine("SUMMARY:Interview Scheduled for Job");
    writer.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:{0}", body.Replace("\n","<br />"));
    //Adding below property actually fixed the issue.
    writer.WriteLine("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", body.Replace("\n","<br />"));
    writer.WriteLine("LOCATION:Test Location");
    writer.WriteLine("PRIORITY:5");
    writer.WriteLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1");
    writer.WriteLine("CLASS:PUBLIC");
    writer.WriteLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
    writer.WriteLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
    writer.WriteLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
    writer.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
    writer.WriteLine("END:VALARM");
    writer.WriteLine("END:VEVENT");
    writer.WriteLine("END:VCALENDAR");

}
```

But Lotus email client is displaying the content as such. 
its showing

```
Dear Raj, <br><br> How are you? line break is not working <br><br> how?
```

On all other email clients, my content is displaying as

```
Dear Raj, 

How are you? line break is not working 

how?
```

Am i missing something here?

**Updated my .ics generation code to add X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html: to fix the issue**

Comment: Shouldn't it be <br/> ? Maybe Lotus Notes is a little more strict about tags...

Comment: I had <br/> but i saw somewhere that Lotus notes does not support standard html tags, so fix gonna be use <br> instead of <br />. Looks like that too didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked with a vcard that contains your Text in Lotus Notes 8.5 and IBM Notes 9, and it worked exactly as expected. BUT: It worked with your "original" Text without the replace. In the [RFC2445](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) it states, that Line- Breaks have to be encoded as \n:

> An intentional formatted text line break MUST only be included in a
>   "TEXT" property value by representing the line break with the
>   character sequence of BACKSLASH (US-ASCII decimal 92), followed by a
>   LATIN SMALL LETTER N (US-ASCII decimal 110) or a LATIN CAPITAL LETTER
>   N (US-ASCII decimal 78), that is "\n" or "\N".

That means: use

```
writer.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:{0}", body);
```

instead of

```
writer.WriteLine("DESCRIPTION:{0}", body.Replace("\n","<br>"));
```

And your problem should be solved

Comment: Rendering of the email is working fine but when you double click on email, it shows "Accept", "Decline" and "Tentative" buttons and here the content of Invitation is displaying as plain text instead of html, that is <br /> is rendering as "<br />" and not line break. If i use original text with out replacing <br />,  text after Dear Raj is not displayed at all. All these happens when I look at the meeting invitation.

Comment: I added one more property fixed the issue:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<body of the email>

Comment: The problem is that it needs to be a literal `\n`, not a real line break.

Answer (score 0):

The DESCRIPTION property is not meant to contain any rich text/html content but only plain text.

Lotus Notes may use some other property (X- property) to convey rich text description. Or it may use an ALTREP parameter on the DESCRIPTION, that point to another MIME bodypart in the invitation. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.1

So what you probably want to do is to send an invitation containing rich text from Lotus Notes to some external account, and then see what the MIME message that  you receive looks like.